# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: java, android, sdk

After updating the Android Studio, I am getting error like

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a major issue you just need to do this

In app level `build.gradle` file use

```
complieSdkVersion 26  
buildToolVersion "26.0.1"
```

This will resolve your error.